# How do I run two Hazelcast nodes that share single data structure?

Tags: java, distributed, hazelcast

Say I have 2 nodes with IPs `192.168.5.101` and `192.168.5.102`. I'd like to launch first one with some task initializing a distributed map and, in a couple of minutes, the second one (on those two hosts). How should I configure them to be able to see one another and to share that Map?

UPD. I had a glance at the Hazelcast docs and managed to run two instances with the following code:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.4.101").addMember("192.168.4.102").setRequiredMember("192.168.4.101").setEnabled(true);
config.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("192.168.4.*");
```

And somewhere further:

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
MultiMap<Long, Long> idToPids = hazelcast.getMultiMap("mapName");
IMap<Long, EntityDesc> idToDesc = hazelcast.getMap("multiMapName");
```

All that followed by some job-performing code. 
I run this class on two different nodes, they successfully see each other and communicate (even share the resources, as far as I can tell).

But the problem is the work of two nodes seems *a lot* slower than in the case of single local node. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons of a slow down is that the data used in the tasks (I don't know anything about them) could be stored on a different member than the task is running. With a single node cluster, you don't have this problem. But with a multi node cluster, the map will be partitioned, so every member will only store a subset of the data.

Also with a single node, there is no backup and therefor it is a lot faster, than in a true clustered setup (so >1 members).

These are some of the obvious reasons why things could slow down. But without additional information, it will be very hard to guess what is the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I got the obvious reasons, but the slowdown is *really* significant, so I'm considering another possibilities. What other information could probably give you more hints? Nature of the tasks is pretty simple - reading from some files into an `IMap` instance. Each node has it's set of files and each file is being read in a separate thread concurrently.

Comment: I don't know of other possibilities without getting access to some code :) How can a doctor cure its patients, if the patient doesn't want to visit.

Comment: I've already shown the *only* difference between those two versions - it's that network configuration and the very fact of running two instances. But, nevertheless, I'll deliver you some pieces of code as soon as I'll get back to work. Thank you for your attention and consideration :)

Comment: Here is the runner code, I hope it'll help to get the issue's cause.  http://pastebin.com/wypiSLUL